# Probleme executing SPARQL query for MESH Endpoint

Tags: java, sparql, jena, ontology

I execute this code on this site [MESH Query](https://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/query) it returns the right results
But when I executed using Jena it returns null.
On Jena

```
String s = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
PREFIX meshv: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/vocab#> 
PREFIX mesh: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/> 
PREFIX mesh2015: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2015/> 
PREFIX mesh2016: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2016/> 
PREFIX mesh2017: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2017/> 
SELECT ?d ?dName ?c ?cName 
FROM <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh> 
WHERE { 
  ?d a meshv:Descriptor .
  ?d meshv:concept ?c . 
  ?d rdfs:label ?dName .
  ?c rdfs:label ?cName 
  FILTER(REGEX(?dName,'infection','i') || REGEX(?cName,'infection','i'))
}
ORDER BY ?d ";
Query query = QueryFactory.create(s);
            QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/sparql", query );
            ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
            ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
```

Comment: I suppose you have to enable RDFS inferencing, probably, via `qe.addParam('inference', 'true')`

Comment: this function does not exist.

Comment: Most likely. The idea is that you have to set `&inference=true` in URL requested. Did you see the "RDFS inference?" checkbox in UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `QueryEngineHTTP` such that you can enable the inference via the HTTP param `inference=true`:

```
Query query = QueryFactory.create(s);
QueryEngineHTTP qe = new QueryEngineHTTP("http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/sparql", query );
qe.addPAram("inference", "true")
ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I edit the query and I have a resut it's not the same because "http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/sparql" don't know meshv:Descriptor so I remove it and now I'm trying to reformulate the query to have the same result

Comment: Why? It is important to understand that you enabled `RDFS inference` in the UI, which is not enabled by default. And there is no direct instance of the class `meshv:Descriptor` that matches your query. The solution is to enabled it in Jena by adding a URL param `&inference=true` as StanislavKralin already suggested in his comment.